# Resource Monitor notifications history

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there is a way to grab the Resource Monitor notifications history in Snowflake? We would like to track and analyze alerts sent by Snowflake Resource Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there isn't an account usage view that supplies this to my knowledge, but you might have to write something custom to support this using metering history views I would guess.

Also, add this as a desired capability to Snowflake's ideas page

Comment: i just learn that you can use this: There's a fairly new table WAREHOUSE_EVENTS_HISTORY that shows a state in the EVENT_REASON description : RESOURCE_MONITOR_SUSPEND . This could get you when a credit quota gets hit, but it won't show you who received the email notification. IIRC it only sends to the account administrators
ref: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/warehouse_events_history.html

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. I am aware of the WH Event Resource History, however, the content is limited.

Comment: You can add that to the snowflake community ideas page and get some for votes for it